# unicode-math: How to include multiple font styles and Unicode symbols in a font range?

Tags: fonts, errors, unicode, unicode-math

I need to include multiple Unicode symbols and font styles to be written in the [Redacted Script font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Redacted+Script). However, this code

```
\documentclass{article}

\tracinglostchars=3 % Make it an error if a glyph is missing from the current font

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO]{Latin Modern Math}

\setmainfont{RedactedScript-Regular.ttf} 

\setmathfont{RedactedScript-Regular.ttf}%
\setmathfont{RedactedScript-Regular.ttf}%
[range = {
    up , it , bb , bbit , scr , cal , bfcal , frak , tt , 
    sfup ,  sfit , bfup , bfit , bfscr , bffrak , bfsfup , bfsfit, "002B, 
    "002D, "2796, "207B , "03B7 , "03BC , "03D5 , "03C1, "2264, "3D, "2212, "03BC
}] 


\begin{document}
    \[\phi\]
\end{document}
```

gets me this error

```
Missing character: There is no ϕ (U+03D5) in font [redacted-script-regular.ttf]
:mode=base;language=dflt;!
.
\endmathdisplay ...admath \fi \endmathdisplay@a $$
                                                  \global \let \df@label \@e...
l.16    \[\phi\]
```

Additionally, what is the meaning of the error message despite the existence of `"03D5` in the font range?

Comment: the error message says the font does not have that character, I don't have the font to check, but it's usually right about those things,

Comment: note the font I downloaded from the google fonts link you gave has name `RedactedScript-Regular.ttf` not as you gave here

Comment: Note this is not "redacting" text in the sense that eg Acrobat will redact text from a PDF, it is OK if printing on paper but the text is all there to be cut and pasted it's just unusual letter shapes which ar anyway lost if you cut and paste or extract the text

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, I need just this unreadable font. However, I wonder if there is a trick to include a symbol in a font range it doesn't belong to.

Comment: you could change the mathcode of every symbol that you use to be a letter a-z eg `\Umathcodenum (sorry I misread your code for commen above I deleted, your math range usage would be fine if the font had the characters)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I hope. whenever possible, you can give me a complete working solution based on my question to fully understand how it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use a font that does not cover the characters you need you may find it easier to redact the characters in Lua replacing tham by `~` or some other character.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\directlua{
function tilderise(n) 
for nn in node.traverse(n) do
if nn.id==0 or nn.id==1 then % hlist and vlist iterate over the lists
  tilderise(nn.head)
elseif nn.id==29 then  % if it is a glyph node change the glyph
  print ('\string\n glyph=' .. nn.char .. '/' .. nn.font) % debugging
  nn.char=126 % this is ~
  nn.font=15  % force a text font as the classic math fonts don't have a ~ in this slot
end
end
return n
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback('pre_output_filter',tilderise,'\string~ filter')
}



\begin{document}
abc XYZ
    \[\phi+\int\frac{a}{1+x}dx\]
\end{document}
```

If you want to start and stop then you need a different callback rather than the full page based output filter, but the same code works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\directlua{
function tilderise(n) 
for nn in node.traverse(n) do
if nn.id==0 or nn.id==1 then % hlist and vlist iterate over the lists
tilderise(nn.head)
elseif nn.id==29 then  % if it is a glyph node change the glyph
print ('\string\n glyph=' .. nn.char .. '/' .. nn.font) % debugging
nn.char=126 % this is ~
nn.font=15  % force a text font as the classic math fonts don't have a ~ in this slot
end
end
return n
end

}


\def\starttilterise{\directlua{
luatexbase.add_to_callback('hpack_filter',tilderise,'\string~ filter')
luatexbase.add_to_callback('append_to_vlist_filter',tilderise,'\string~ filter')
}}
\def\stoptilterise{\directlua{
luatexbase.remove_from_callback('hpack_filter','\string~ filter')
luatexbase.remove_from_callback('append_to_vlist_filter','\string~ filter')
}}

\begin{document}
    \starttilterise
    abc XYZ
    \[\phi+\int\frac{a}{1+x}dx\]

    \stoptilterise
    abc XYZ
    \[\phi+\int\frac{a}{1+x}dx\]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my original document, your solution doesn't redact the headers/footers.

Comment: your document as posted here dousn't have a footer, You could just use a different callback instead or as well as this one, that applies to the header box (I thought this would  but I'd need to check and it's too late today, someone in a better timezone may comment)

Comment: @Diaa add `luatexbase.add_to_callback('hpack_filter',tilderise,'\string~ filter')`

Comment: Is it possible to localize the redaction? Like `\begin{redaction} ... \end{redaction}`

Comment: @Diaa sure, just  take `luatexbase.add_to_callback('pre_output_filter',tilderise,'\string~ filter')` out of the definition block then define `\def\startzzz{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback('pre_output_filter',tilderise,'\string~ filter')}}` and `def\stopzzz{\directluaa{luatexbase.remove_from_callback('pre_output_filter','\string~ filter')}}`  then use `\startzzz` to start and `\stopzzz` to stop. (or hpack filter if using that)

Comment: Is this what you mean https://pastebin.com/6hmz2R9c?

Comment: @Diaa you copied before my edit: luatexbase starts with an l

Comment: Would you please show me what changes need to be made for this https://pastebin.com/rbiq4m3w to make it work?

Comment: I am sorry but is there any advice about my last comment?

Comment: @Diaa updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Note the font I downloaded from the google fonts link you gave has name `RedactedScript-Regular.ttf` not as you gave here.

If you look at the font in a font editor such as fontforge you will see that it does not have most of the Greek characters.

U+03D5 is highlighted here.

[image]

Comment: I might have cited a different source; I will check. On the other side, have I done it correctly to include those math font styles and symbols in the font range?

Comment: So, what is the most efficient way to completely censor a text/math document in the redacted font by just a simple command?

Comment: @Diaa nothing particularly simple comes to mind, but also as I commented under the question this isn't redacting anything, all the text is still there so it is only useful if printing on paper not if distributing the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly, the middle `\setmathfont{RedactedScript-Regular.ttf}`, overriding your first math font without a `range=` qualifier, is an error.

You usually want something like

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase} % Or sometimes MatchUppercase
\setmathfont{SomeFallbackMathFont}
\setmathfont{SomeTextFont-Regular}[range=up]
\setmathfont{SomeTextFont-Italic}[range=it]
\setmathfont{SomeTextFont-Bold}[range=bfup]
\setmathfont{SomeTextFont-BoldItalic}[range=bfit]
```

If, however, your font doesn’t contain the `\phi` character, you might either try `\varphi`, or change `range=it` to `range=it/{Latin,latin}`.  This leaves the Greek alphabet unchanged from your fallback font.

If you end up wanting to use the `\varphi` symbol for `\phi` consistently, you can add

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\phi{\varphi}}
```

Comment: I am sorry but what would be your complete working solution of my question? I need to use **only** `RedactedScript-Regular` for **all** the characters in text and math modes with every possible style and weight. So, how to achieve what I need efficiently?

Comment: @Diaa I don’t believe I have that font to check. Unless it’s an OpenType math font, that will be impossible. Do you have a link?

Comment: @Diaa If you’re trying to obfuscate the answers on an exam, it’s not going to work like you hope, because people will be able to copy and paste the characters in Redacted Script. However, if you can remove that metadata, the solution would be to reload the font for every individual alphabet, like the above but also for `cal`, `bfcal`, `bb`, `bbit`, etc.

Comment: @Diaa Alternatively, maybe create boxes the same size as the math atoms, and fill them with random letters.

Comment: Please, check the link to the font files in my question body. I don't care about copying and pasting; I just need to blur all the words printed on a paper.

Comment: Alao, in the comments of David, he suggested using Umathcodenum to apply the font to the symbols not included in the font. However, I don't know how.

Comment: @Davislor the font doesn't have much more than a-z

Comment: @Diaa it depends why you are doing this. The easiest way is \def\phi{p} then you will get a twiddle for `\phi` but if you really need a phi in the underlying text data in the PDF them it would be simplest to find a different font that did this for Greek and not just a-z.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I need to completely redact the whole document.